# Convergence of non-negative sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Say I have a sequence $a^{(n)}$ such that for all $n, a^{(n)} \geq 0$ and $a^{(n)} \rightarrow c.$ Does this imply that $c \geq 0$ and if so from what theorem/definition does it follow?

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it from definition of limit.

HINT: suppose $c<0$. Then $\varepsilon=-c/2>0$, so by definition, for all sufficiently large $n$, you have $|a^{(n)}-c|<\varepsilon$. Derive contradiction from this.